# How to extract war files at specific location through command prompt or using java?

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Hi i am in search of logic that extract war files.
 like in tomcat it extract war in to

```
- META-INF
- Web-INF
-resources
```

i have already gone through link where

> jar -xvf -c abc.war outputdirectory
>   but it doesn't work.let me know if there is some clue.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html

Comment: thanx for your link but i got the solution.when i tried above command(jar -xvf) by changing extension of ".war" to ".jar." it works.